# NHibernate mapping one table on two classes with where selection

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping, mapping

We would like to map a single table on two classes with NHibernate. The mapping has to be dynamically depending on the value of a column.

Here's a simple example to make it a bit clearer:
We have a table called Person with the columns id, Name and Sex.

[image]

The data from this table should be mapped either on the class Male or on the class Female depending on the value of the column Sex.

[image]

In Pseudocode:

```
create instance of Male with data from table Person where Person.Sex = 'm';
create instance of Female with data from table Person where Person.Sex = 'f';
```

The benefit is we have strongly typed domain models and can later avoid switch statements.

Is this possible with NHibernate or do we have to map the Person table into a flat Person class first? Then afterwards we would have to use a custom factory method that takes a flat Person instance and returns a Female or Male instance. 
Would be good if NHibernate (or another library) can handle this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is quite a common case for NHibernate. You can map whole class hierarchies into a single table.

You need to specify a discriminator value.

```
<class name="Person">
  <id .../>

  <discriminator column="Sex" type="string" length="1" />

  <property name="Name"/>
  <!-- add more Person-specific properties here -->

  <subclass name="Male" discriminator-value="m">
    <!-- You could add Male-specific properties here. They 
     will be in the same table as well. Or just leave it empty. -->
  </subclass>

  <subclass name="Female" discriminator-value="f">
    <!-- You could add Female-specific properties here. They 
     will be in the same table as well. Or just leave it empty. -->
  </subclass>

</class>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected.
Would have been strange if it wasn't supported. This is one of things OR/M is made for.